# Configuring max and min parameters in @size validation annotation through properties

Tags: java, spring, validation

Normally, we would validate a model with some constraint like so:

```
public class PersonForm {
    @NotNull
    @Size(min=2, max=30)
    private String name;

    @NotNull
    @Min(18)
    private Integer age;
}
```

However, I would like to use configurable properties instead of constants in my implementation. For instance, let this the `properties` file:

```
personform.name.size.min=2
personform.name.size.max=30
```

and the form class...

```
public class PersonForm {
    @NotNull
    @Size(min="personform.name.size.min", max="personform.name.size.max")
    private String name;

    ...
}
```

Is this possible with a declarative, annotation-based approach? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Try using Spring Expression language in annotation

```
 @Size(min="${personform.name.size.min}", max="${personform.name.size.max}")
private String name;
```

Comment: I'm sorry but this does not work, it says *Incompatible types. Found `java.lang.String`, required: `int`*. What do you think?

Comment: sorry this is valid for strings only https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-8716, i'm trying to find more about it @Leviathlon